# Scala .init method example

Tags: scala

Can you please explain what `init` method performs with respect to below list
i can see the result of new list says that last sequence is being omitted from the existing list.

```
val numbers = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

val result = numbers.init
println(result)
```

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/immutable/List.html.

Answer (score 2):

`.init` and `.last` are the compliments to the `.head` and `.tail` methods.

```
val nums = List(1,2,3,4)

nums.head  //res0: Int = 1
nums.tail  //res1: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)

nums.init  //res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
nums.last  //res3: Int = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

`def init: List[A]` which selects all elements except the last.

```
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

scala> l.last
res58: Int = 8

scala> l.init
res59: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val testList = List(1,2,3,4,5)
 testList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> testList.init
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> testList.last
res1: Int = 5

scala> testList.head
res2: Int = 1

scala> testList.tail
res3: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5)
```